# Create sub paths and full path for item in list

Tags: ansible

I have this list:

```yaml
my_list:
  - /tmp/one/two
  - /root/whatever
```

How do I configure Ansible to return:

```yaml
/tmp
/tmp/one
/tmp/one/two
/root
/root/whatever
```

I've tried splitting by `/`, but that only returns each single element separately.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to loop the `dirname` filter until there is no more parent directories.  Hardcoding this would not be an option. `{{ var | dirname | dirname }}`

Comment: Perhaps we can use count or something? I’m on mobile, can’t test yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jinja below does the job

```yaml
  result: |
    {% for i in my_list|map('split', '/') %}
    {% for j in range(2, i|length +1) %}
    {{ i[:j]|join('/') }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

---

Q: ***"Save it as a list."***

A: Wrap the [YAML list](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#741-flow-sequences) (items separated by comma `,` closed in brackets `[]`) in the [Jinja section filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#id11) and use the filter [from_yaml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json)

```yaml
  result: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    [{% for i in my_list|map('split', '/') %}
    {% for j in range(2, i|length +1) %}
    {{ i[:j]|join('/') }},
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}]
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  result:
  - /tmp
  - /tmp/one
  - /tmp/one/two
  - /root
  - /root/whatever
```

Comment: Would it be possible to save each item as a list straight away? I can convert it to a list w another task, but perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: Yes. I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is almost no description about the Use Case, what the input could be look like including edge cases, extremes, etc., not sure if the following minimal and lazy example could be a feasible approach

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    my_list:
      - /tmp/one/two
      - /root/whatever

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ my_list + (my_list | map('dirname')) + ['/tmp'] }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - /tmp/one/two
  - /root/whatever
  - /tmp/one
  - /root
  - /tmp
```

In the example it is considered that there is in any case a `/tmp` directory. Then just [append list variable to another list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31045409/6771046).

With the [`unique` filter – set of unique items of a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unique_filter.html) in order to [restrict list to unique elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809647/6771046) it would be possible to clean up if the path is only one level deep. In example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    my_list:
      - /tmp/one
      - /root/what/ever

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ (my_list + (my_list | map('dirname')) + ['/tmp', '/root']) | unique }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - /tmp/one
  - /root/what/ever
  - /tmp
  - /root/what
  - /root
```

For all other cases one may [accept the here given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78150520/6771046) as it is the most generic approach and will for work for deep path structures.

Comment: Hhm, now you manually configured /tmp and /root in your debug statement.

Comment: Right, as mentioned it is a lazy approach where it assumed that the root paths are everytime tmp and or root, as well the path is not deeper than three. For a generic approach for all path names and all depth, there is already the other answer which I’ve voted up.

Comment: Yeah alright :)!